# How to Computed Two Results For Two Target Element in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can someone please let me know if there is a way to have two `result()` in Vue `computed` based on element id?
For example I want return into `#and` a result which is replaced comma with `AND`
and an other result for `#dash` which in this result is replaced with `-`

[image]

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      target: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    result() {
      //if it is going to #and
      // return '`' + this.target.replaceAll(",", "` AND `") + '`' // If {{ result }} is #and
      // if it is going to #dash
      return '`' + this.target.replaceAll(",", "` - `") + '`' // If {{ result }} is #dash
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <p id="and">You Entered {{ result }}</p>
  <p id="dash">You Entered {{ result }}</p>
  <input v-model="target" placeholder="Enter Your Target" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function instead:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() { return { target: '' } },
  methods: {
    getSeperatedInputVal(sep) {
      return this.target && 
        this.target.split(',').map(str => '`'+ str + '`').join(sep);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <p id="and">You Entered {{ getSeperatedInputVal(" AND ") }}</p>
  <p id="dash">You Entered {{ getSeperatedInputVal(" - ") }}</p>
  <input v-model="target" placeholder="Enter Your Target" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Majed, this is what I was lookin  for, but there is one minor issue here. as you can see the outputs look like  `'rome AND london AND rome'` but they should be  `'rome' AND 'london' AND 'rome'`

Comment: @Suffii you're welcome, check now